# How to get sample of data by having best possible equal number of rows from multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, random, sample

**Data:**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(100, 4)), 
                       columns=list('ABCD'))

df1["cat1"] = np.random.choice(['a', 'b'], len(df1))
df1["cat2"] = np.random.choice(['32782', '35871', '35865'], len(df1))
df1["cat3"] = np.random.choice(['pq', 'xy', 'ab', 'hq'], len(df1))
```

I want to take sample of this dataset i.e., 200 rows by having max possible equal number of row from each category of 3 columns

We can validate like,

```
assert len(sample['a']) == len(sample['b'])
assert len(sample['32782']) == len(sample['35871'] == len(sample['35865']))
assert len(sample['pq']) == len(sample['xy'] == len(sample['ab'] == len(sample['hq'])))
```

In my there are 100M rows and I want to take 200K rows.

I tried to use `sample = df1.sample(n=200000, replace=True, random_state=123)` to take the 200K rows, but not sure how to use randome sample i.e., `df1.sample` to get best possible equal number of rows from each group?

Having exact same rows is not a strict condition, even +/- 5% error is also fine.

Update:

`replace=True` is used to get repeat rows, if `n` is small.

Comment: Do you need 3 ouputs, like `df1.groupby('cat1').sample(n=200000, random_state=123)`, `df1.groupby('cat2').sample(n=200000, random_state=123)` and `df1.groupby('cat3').sample(n=200000, random_state=123)` ?

Comment: @jezrael No, I need to single output that container same number rows for each unique category. Overall dataset size is `200000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.groupby()` and then apply `sample`:

```
n = 1
df1.groupby(['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3']).apply(lambda s: s.sample(n))
```

You can use `.reset_index(drop=True)` to drop the index if you wish.

Only `n=1` works with my dummy example as there was a combination of categories that only existed once. If the dataset is larger, possibly larger values for `n` are acceptable.

To find the maximum value for `n`, you need to groupby the three categories and count the number of occurances (also include the zero occurances). Then take the minimum which is your maximum value for `n`:

```
from itertools import product
combs = pd.DataFrame(list(product(df1['cat1'].unique(), df1['cat2'].unique(), df1['cat3'].unique())),
                     columns=['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3'])
groupby = df1.groupby(['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3']).size().reset_index()
result = groupby.merge(combs, how = 'right').fillna(0)

n_max = int(result[0].min())
```

You can verify that this is indeed the maximum value by plugging in `n = n_max + 1` in the code on top, as this will give an error.

Output:

```
                      A    B    C    D cat1   cat2 cat3
cat1 cat2  cat3                                        
a    32782 ab   60  369  281  970  277    a  32782   ab
           hq   8    94  933  560  622    a  32782   hq
           pq   65  369  356  120  533    a  32782   pq
           xy   3   227  267  664  161    a  32782   xy
     35865 ab   45  991  929  664  400    a  35865   ab
           hq   10   52  337  303  804    a  35865   hq
           pq   2   639  557  828   90    a  35865   pq
           xy   57  823  882   11  574    a  35865   xy
     35871 ab   98  900  331  527  966    a  35871   ab
           hq   70  132  394  235  177    a  35871   hq
           pq   9   660  411  342  752    a  35871   pq
           xy   79  617  780  555  649    a  35871   xy
b    32782 ab   35  820  962  374  180    b  32782   ab
           hq   22  813   53  919  840    b  32782   hq
           pq   18  682  449  660  226    b  32782   pq
           xy   73  471  578  267   29    b  32782   xy
     35865 ab   77  301  953  121  525    b  35865   ab
           hq   43  700  312  947  339    b  35865   hq
           pq   59  307  259  287  749    b  35865   pq
           xy   61  552  164  129   53    b  35865   xy
     35871 ab   68  113  678  805  226    b  35871   ab
           hq   88  533  732  359  891    b  35871   hq
           pq   74  416  279  407  387    b  35871   pq
           xy   7   848  776  779  719    b  35871   xy
```

Comment: How to find the right value for `n`? I was expecting best possible max number for `n`.

Comment: Do you want duplicate rows in your sample?

Comment: Ideally, it should not. As I was not able to find the best possible max number logic, I used `replace=True` which is producing duplicates :(

Comment: I edited my answer to find `n_max`. With using `replace=False` (default) you will not get any duplicates

Comment: For my real dataset, `n_max` is coming as `zero`. Instead of `min` can I use `mean` or `median` value?

Comment: Well, this means that there is a combination of categories that does not exist in your dataframe. What you want to with that is up to you ;)

Comment: Got it. Thanks for providing the solution and quick response!